# Does two opened projects take twice the memory heap or does it split up?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I set the IDE memory heap to 2048MbB and open two projects at the same time, does it uses twice the memory heap configured for the IDEA (4096MB) or does it split up (1024MB) for each?

Comment: The memory you set for the IDE is shared among all projects you open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not increase your machine's heap memory if you open 2 to 3 windows of separate projects. You can check it by yourself, open multiple projects and take a snapshot of your machine's resources.